# How to organize my cake views

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and started an application with it.
I am facing a problem how to better organize my view.

My application has Categories and Categories have related products.
in head I want to display all available categories and as user click on a Category name all it's related product will be displayed under Categories list.

Should I define both Categories and Product show in a single view? or a view which extends these to view and where should I created these views? As these belong to 2 different models.

And how data will be feteched as I want to access product of only selected category not for all categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to cakePHP I would recommend to "bake" the controllers, models and views for your Categories and Products. When you bake them, you will be able to define the one-to-many-relation between both (Product `belongs_to` Category and Category `has_many` Products).

The result will be, that the Category-views automatically contain a list of related Products.

(You have to bake Category first and Product after that...)

Comment: Fernando is correct- The next step for someone pretty new to cakePHP who has arranged their database appropriately should use the bake utility to first bake models from their databases- the utility will guess and ask you to confirm what the relationships are based off the database fields- then bake controllers, which will provide a default set of actions that you can later modify, then bake views for each controller.